# instantiate a class python

Tags: python, class, static

in python -
there is reason to instantiate a class with just static variables and static methods?
for example -

```
StaticClass:
   first_static_variable = "first arbitrary value"
   first_static_variable = "second arbitrary value"

   @staticmethod
   def just_static_method():
       return "arbitrary value"
```

I'm asking if there is good reason to do -

```
static_class = StaticClass()
```

or should I do

```
static_class = StaticClass
```

or it doesn't matter at all.

I'm going to use this class just one time.

Comment: Your static methods and class data attributes (which you consider as static variables) are accessible from class object. No need to create instance. `static_class = StaticClass` would suffice.

Comment: I know that it suffice, what is the best practice?

Comment: Yes, it is best practice to put in a new variable, as we expect that each instance is independent.
var_1, var_2, n..

Answer (score 0):

Based on this example (you missed the `class` keyword):

```py
class StaticClass:
   first_static_variable = "first arbitrary value"
   first_static_variable = "second arbitrary value"

   @staticmethod
   def just_static_method():
       return "arbitrary value"

print(StaticClass)
print(StaticClass())
```

output is:

```
<class '__main__.StaticClass'>
<__main__.StaticClass object at 0x7fea2cb33a60>
```

The parentheses tell Python to create an instance of the class, and a lack of them will only assign a reference to the class.

Sometimes, you could rather use a module just to store values and functions. Assume two files: `main.py` and `deps.py`, both in the same directory.

`deps.py`:

```py
import re

def is_numeric(s):
  return bool(re.search("\A[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+\Z", s))
```

`main.py`:

```py
import deps

print(deps.is_numeric("-19.1")) # test, prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making static methods, then because of methods belongs to a class not to an object, you don't have to initialize the class. You can just basically call your methods from class directly. For example in your code you can call your method `StaticClass.just_static_method()`. And if you want to know about the difference between a static variable and a normal class variable(fields), a static variable is global to all objects but fields are private only for its objects. For the difference between static an non-static methods, as far as I know they are only different because of their runtime situations. I hope this is helpful enough.